# Why do strings containing angle brackets get swallowed by the renderer?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

Why when I type a string like IOrderedQueryable'<'TModel'>'

```
IOrderedQueryable<TModel>
```

in answer part without adding spaces before it to make it code part, it wasn't shown in my sentence? I voted down because of this problem.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean as it is difficult (for me anyway) to understand what you mean.

Comment: If my guess is right, you are talking about `<` part in the code... This is otherwise interpreted as html elements in the editor( if not formatted as code ) and will be parsed. The editor allows some HTML tags for formatting.

Comment: Although I agree with @Script47 this question needs to be clarified..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bug, but how the markdown works.

If you have HTML tag like expressions somewhere in your text like `<TModel>`, the renderer tries to apply this as HTML tag, and if it's not supported, nothing is shown.